# Error in setting up Fuchsia

Tags: linux, bash, git, google-chrome-os

I was trying to build Fuchsia. During importing the source, it says to add `/fuchsia/.jiri_root/bin` to my PATH. I did it but the ERROR says,

```
Updating all projects
ERROR: 'git fetch -p origin' failed:
stdout:

stderr:
fatal: unable to access 'https://fuchsia.googlesource.com/third_party/github.com/kr/fs/': gnutls_handshake() failed: The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.

command fail error: exit status 128

Wait for 5s before next attempt...: Fetching for /home/amim/fuchsia/third_party/golibs/github.com/kr/fs

Attempt 2/3: Fetching for /home/amim/fuchsia/third_party/golibs/github.com/kr/fs

ERROR: context deadline exceeded
```

Though there were errors, I tried the `jiri` command and it works. And then, I tried `fx` that was located in `scripts/fx`, it says `Cannot find Platform Source Tree containing /home/amim`

How can I solve these problems?